# How to delete MediaWiki deleted categories?

Tags: mediawiki

In `https://example.com/index.php?title=special:categories` there are two category-page links:

- Blue ones: For existing category pages
- Red ones: For non-existing category pages but are still known by the system

Red ones can be of two sub types:

1. Category pages that have a link to but have yet to be created
2. Category pages that were created and no longer exist - deleted.

How could I remove all red links to category pages I already deleted (type 2), from that very web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Special:Categories` is a list of the categories the pages of that wiki have been categorized into, regardless of whether the category pages of those categories are created or not. In other words, if you add `[[Category:Foo]]` to the end of page `Bar`, that will add `Foo` to the list. Whatever you do with the `Category:Foo` page won't change that.

Comment: Tgr, in other words, there is no way to delete these besides a dangerous dive into the SQL database (which I will avoid from)? Thanks,

Comment: Sure there is, just edit all pages which are in the category, and remove the category tag from them. There are all kinds of tools to make that easier, e.g. pywikibot's [category.py](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot/category.py).